# Why I can't get the ID from group by along with Count(ID)?

Tags: soql, aggregate

My goal is to get the ID and the COUNT(ID) [ie.expr0]. ? But i am struggling here!  Any other way

```
  SELECT  COUNT(Id),Id, Application_Prefix__c FROM Test__c GROUP BY Application_Prefix__c  //ERROR Id should be group by
```

i tried

```
SELECT COUNT(Id),Id, Application_Prefix__c FROM Test__c GROUP BY Application_Prefix__c,Id //ERROR aggregate can't be used in group by
```

Comment: You can't have count(Id) and have Id in the select close ! if you don't group by Id

Comment: You seem to be having an **[X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info)** here. You've selected an approach that is not possible within the constraints of the Salesforce platform. If you back up and explain what you are trying to achieve at a high level, you will get better advisement. Please **[edit]** your post to be more clear about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Agree. Updating the post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to count how many records match each `Application_Prefix__c`, then you should remove `Id` from your `SELECT` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), Application_Prefix__c FROM Test__c GROUP BY Application_Prefix__c
```

You can't really get both the individual Id values and the count per prefix in a single query. If you wanted to get the counts using post-processing, you could do a `Map<String, List<Test__c>>` or even just a `Map<String, Integer>`. Here is a common grouping pattern:

```
List<Test__c> allRecords = [SELECT Application_Prefix__c FROM Test__c];
Map<String, List<Test__c>> prefixes = new Map<Id, List<Test__c>();
for (Test__c record : allRecords)
{
    if (!prefixes.containsKey(record.Application_Prefix__c))
        prefixes.put(record.Application_Prefix__c, new List<Test__c>());
    prefixes.get(record.Application_Prefix__c).add(record);
}
```

Comment: Yes. But i need to pull the ID from the aggregate query to process some other record which is depend on this id value. I dont want to go for another SOQL to pull the ID.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all. Aggregates by definition represent more than one record...

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be with the order of your statements related to Id.

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(Id), Application_Prefix__c FROM Test__c GROUP BY Application_Prefix__c, Id
```

**Edit**

Problem is caused by trying to use groupBy on a field that you're also aggregating. I think you may want to try using [Group by Rollup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_rollup.htm) or possibly [Grouping](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_grouping.htm) if you don't want to manually calculate the count.

Comment: Count(Id) and groub by Id in that case I think that Count(Id) will be equal to 1

Comment: You'll only have one Count(Id) record, but you'll have all of the record Ids. Perhaps you want to groupby Application_Prefix__c ?

Comment: Got error [object Object]: SELECT Id, COUNT(Id), Application_Prefix__c FROM Test__c GROUP BY Application_Prefix__c, Id ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:18 Grouped field should not be aggregated: I

Comment: Not sure, aggregateResult object is a list and can contain multiple values, in this cas as much as there is Ids

Comment: Aggregate result is a list. What I suggest is that you remove the count(ID) and since you have all the Ids, count them manually or run the query again separately. Your error is because you're grouping on the field that you're also aggregating. Remove the groupby clause and you'd be fine with the above query.

Comment: @crmprogdev good suggestion !

Comment: See Group By Rollup mentioned in edits