# Search items from list and get count

Tags: soql, map, list, set, count

I have a list of accounts from SOQL as below:

```
List<Account> accList = [Select ID, Name, MyField__c From Account where course__r.status = 'active'];
```

I have added the values of `MyField__c` from this list into a Set. Because I need to pass it for another query.

```
Set<Id> accIds = new Set<Id>();
for(Account accountField :  accList ) {
     accIds.add(accountField.MyField__c);
}
```

//Get account group based on the set of IDs

```
List<AccountGroups__c> accGroups = [Select ID, GroupName__c , AssociatedAccount__c , AssociatedAccount__r.Name from AccountGroups__c where AssociatedAccount__c IN: accIds ];
```

//Create a Map of ID and AccountGroup

Now, for each account - I want to get the count of AccountGroups__c .

```
for (Account account : accList )
{
      // How to get AccountGroups__c for each account
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Aggregate Functions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/167134/why-i-cant-get-the-id-from-group-by-along-with-countid). For example:

```
AggregateResult[] agrs = [SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM AccountGroups__c GROUP BY AssociatedAccount__c];

for(AggregateResult agr : agrs){
    System.debug('Count of AccountGroups__c per AssociatedAccount__c: ' + agr.get('expr0'));
}
```